# Breaking Array Values as Characters

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array with ascii characters values like this

```
arryAsc[] = [97, 100, 97, 115, 100]
```

Now I want to make an array arrSplit[] and want to save these values in array like this.

```
arrSplit[] = [9, 7, 1, 0, 0, 9, 7, 1, 1, 5, 1, 0, 0]
```

If anyone can help thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That does not look like a valid use of the [] syntax to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this :

```
var a:Array = [97, 100, 97, 115, 100];

var b:Array = a.join('').split('');

trace(b);   // gives : 9,7,1,0,0,9,7,1,1,5,1,0,0
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks akmozo your solutions if perfect and working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array, casting each element as a String, then use [split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()) with an empty string as delimiter to break apart each string into an array of characters. You can use [concat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#concat()) to combine all the smaller arrays back into your larger `arrSplit` array.

Comment: yes split is used for this I have solved my issue. Thanks